# Strings and List of Strings in Mustache - Java

Tags: java, html, mustache

is there a simple way to output Strings and List of Strings with Mustache in a HTML-File?

I started to make a HashMap with all the information:

```
hashMap1.put("time", a.getTime().toString());
```

And so on. But i also want to write a `List<String>` into the html file. How can I do that properly?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware, that Mustache can handle Object directly. I solved my problem with the following implementation:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I correctly understand your question. Do you just want to convert a List of strings into single string? If so you could either use

```
Arrays.toString(newList.toArray());
```

which prints in a format

```
[string-1][string-2]...[string-n]
```

The other option is to use `String.join(" separator ", newList);` which prints out

```
string-1 separator string-2 separator (...) separator string-n
```